# Plot an infinite sum

Tags: plotting, summation, infinite-loop

I want to plot the following equation (w-$\delta$ graph)

[image]

Ty Tx and ly are constant and I will assign a value for them. I am a new one on the Mathematica and can not handle this.

Comment: It seems that this sum cannot be found symbolically, however there is numerical sum `NSum` which can be computed with numerical values of constants e.g. `With[{Tx = 0.6, Ty = 0.93}, 
 NSum[(-1)^(
   n - 1)/(2 n - 1)^3 (1 - 1/
     Cosh[(2 n - 1) Pi/(2 Tx) Sqrt[Ty/Tx]]), {n, 1, Infinity}]]`

Comment: Thank you. I also tried Sum[f,{n, 1, Infinity, 2}] and think it works pretty well.